# WPF: word-break wrapping

Tags: wpf, xaml

```
<Paragraph>
    <TextBlock TextWrapping="Wrap" TextAlignment="Left">
        aaaaaaaaa bbbbbbbbbb cccccccccc dddddddd
    </TextBlock>
</Paragraph>
```

I expect word-break wrapping like console.

```
|-------------------------|
aaaaaaaaa bbbbbbbbbb cccccc
cccc dddddddd
```

But, actual output is below.

```
|-------------------------|
aaaaaaaaa bbbbbbbbbb
cccccccccc dddddddd
```

Is there `word-break` option such as css?

Comment: Since there is no such feature; if you know the character width, break the string manually before binding.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you can see in the [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.textwrapping.aspx) there is no such option. The available values for TextWrapping are:

> **NoWrap**  No line wrapping is performed.
>
> **Wrap**  Line-breaking occurs if the line overflows beyond the available block width, even if the standard line breaking algorithm cannot determine any line break opportunity, as in the case of a very long word constrained in a fixed-width container with no scrolling allowed.
>
> **WrapWithOverflow**   Line-breaking occurs if the line overflows beyond the available block width. However, a line may overflow beyond the block width if the line breaking algorithm cannot determine a line break opportunity, as in the case of a very long word constrained in a fixed-width container with no scrolling allowed.